# Volume / Measure of unit $n$-ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\alpha_n$ be the volume of a n-ball of radius 1.

I need to prove that $\displaystyle \alpha_n=\alpha_{n-1}\cdot \int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{(n-1)/2}dx$.

The formula seems to suggest that, instead of the usual way of integrating by slices(adding the slices whose size will depend on $x$), we pick the n-1 ball and 'rotate' it to create the n-ball.
So my question is how do I write mathematically the reasoning of rotating the line?

However, when applying this reasoning of rotating If I $\pi$-rotate the line segment from -1 to 1, I should get the area of a unit circle,but $\alpha_2=\pi\neq\alpha_1\cdot \pi=2\cdot\pi$.

P.S.: I'm study by myself. This exercise was taken from Fleming's Functions of Several Variables.

Comment: I could suggest another method to get to the recurrence is by multiple integrals.

Comment: That should be $\alpha_1 \cdot \pi/2$ instead of $\alpha_1 \cdot \pi$. You probably integrated wrong. The idea itself is correct

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän The idea of rotating? But then isn't rotating [-1,1] by $\pi$, just multiplying Lenghtof[-1,1] by $\pi$? I do not understand how I can write it mathematically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The formula seems to suggest that, instead of the usual way of integrating by slices(adding the slices whose size will depend on $x$), we pick the $n-1$ ball and 'rotate' it to create the $n$-ball.

Note that your formula *can* be interpreted in terms of slicing. Assume $n \geq 2$, and for each real number $x$ let
$$
\mathbf{R}_x^{n-1}
  = \mathbf{R}^{n - 1} \times \{x\}
  = \{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n) : x_n = x\} \subset \mathbf{R}^n.
$$
If $B^n$ denotes the unit ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$, then (up to translation) the slice $B^n \cap \mathbf{R}_x^{n-1}$ is (if $-1 \leq x \leq 1$) a ball of radius $r(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}$, or (if $|x| > 1$) is empty. The $n$-dimensional volume of $B^n$ may be found by integrating the $(n-1)$-dimensional volumes of the slices:
$$
\alpha_n = \int_{-1}^1 \operatorname{vol}\bigl(B_{r(x)}^{n-1}\bigr)\, dx.
$$
Your recursion formula follows easily if you remember that the volume of an $(n-1)$-ball of radius $r$ is $\alpha_{n-1} r^{n-1}$. (The "base case" for your recursion is $\alpha_1 = 2$, the length of the unit ball in $\mathbf{R}$.)

Tangentially, I don't see any way of interpreting your recursion formula in terms of rotations. A "rotation" of $\mathbf{R}^n$ is really "rotation in a plane", not "rotation about a line axis". (The two notions coincide only when $n = 3$.) Consequently, I know of no way to rotate an $(n-1)$-ball (or some part of one) in order to "sweep out" an $n$-ball in a way conducive to finding the volume recursively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unless there the exercises are badly planned or I misread something, I think I'm not supposed to use that relation of $\alpha_{n-1}r^{n-1}$ for the volume, because the book, when proving that relation for any radius, assumes the formula for the unit ball, and calculates its volume under an affine transformation (change of variables). If I were allowed to use it, your answer would be fine. In fact, it was the first think I thought of.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea: If I understand your comment right, your book has (sensibly) split the calculation of $\alpha_n$. First, let $\alpha_n$ _denote_ the (as yet unknown) volume of the _unit_ $n$-ball, and argue that the volume of an $n$-ball of radius $r > 0$ is $\alpha_n r^n$. (This argument is independent of your original question.) Then, express $\alpha_n$ recursively in terms of $\alpha_{n-1}$, which is the content of your original question.

Comment: I'll paraphrase the book, since English is not my native language. «Let $\alpha_n$ denote the measure of an n-ball of radius 1. Then $V_n(H)=1/2\alpha_n$. (...) In Section 5.9 we give a general formula for $\alpha_n$. Let us use the intuitively evident fact that the measure of an n-ball of radius $r$ is $\alpha_n r^n$ This follows from th.5.7, Section 5.7» This sentence is in section 5.5. The theorem 5.7 is just shows how to calculate the volume for a affine transformation when we know the volume of the domain.
Maybe I'm just mixing things up, but the book usually has difficult exer

Comment: cises. I put a link where you can obtain online the book. http://en.bookfi.org/book/580162 This is in page 198 and 199 (printed version) and I'm trying to do exercise 7.
I like it, in some parts more than in others. It's a good buy, I think...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea: Thank you for posting the book. Since Fleming writes, in Example 5 on p. 198, "...the intuitively evident fact that the measure of an $n$-ball of radius $r$ is $\alpha_n r^n$", I'd guess you're "allowed" to use this fact in Exercise 7 on p. 199. It appears your initial idea is what Fleming had in mind. :)  [Note that there's no logical circle in arguing this way, see my previous comment.]

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understand what you're saying. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

When [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%20from%20-1%20to%201) does the integral for $n=2$ it gets $\frac \pi 2$.  In fact, $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt {1-x^2} dx $ is just the area of the half unit circle above the $x$ axis.